Need help with ER diagram for my pet project
Right now, I have started to learn more about databases. One of the topics that I have more questions about is the relationships between tables. For example, I am currently trying to create an ER diagram for a project where you would first buy a plant and then receive notifications about when it needs watering. Could you please let me know if my connections are correct and if they need any improvements?
